# Split text into country/location, departemnt and topic and group them

Tags: python, machine-learning

I have the task of splitting title that look like this:

- at production plant reporting --> country/location:at, dept: production, topic: reporting
- us it project management office --> country/location:at, dept: production, topic: reporting
- grp it power bi administration --> country/location:grp, dept: it, topic: power bi administration
- grp all reporting --> default title for general content
- br big data analytics reporting --> country/location:br, dept: big data analytics, topic: reporting
- grp production shopfloor management --> country/location:grp, dept: production, topic: shopfloor management
- grp all power bi training --> country/location:grp, dept: all, topic: power bi training
- grp it power bi release plan --> country/location:grp, dept: all, topic: power bi release plan
- grp it power bi monitoring --> country/location:grp, dept: all, topic: power bi monitoring

But it doesnt end there, big data analytics belong to the IT department, the real answer should be

- br big data analytics reporting --> country/location:br, dept: it, topic: reporting

production belongs to operation, so

- grp production shopfloor management --> country/location:grp, dept: operations, topic: shopfloor management

In the case of the three last title, the topic should be power bi only, the rest is just extra detail

- grp all power bi training --> country/location:grp, dept: all, topic: power bi
- grp it power bi release plan --> country/location:grp, dept: all, topic: power bi
- grp it power bi monitoring --> country/location:grp, dept: all, topic: power bi

I have tried splitting them *the best I could*, because to get the dept and topic sometimes I need to understand the context of the title.
I create a departments.json file with objects containing the name of a department and the most common words/phrases related to that department. I split the tiltles and iterate over it then, I apply the fuzz.token_sort_ratio function to see if the current word belongs to this department.

How would you approach this problem?
Can I use ML to classify the titles?

Answer (score 0):

If every title has information on all the attributes, I would do it by hand (if you a beginner on ML).

This would be the procedure I'd choose:

```
location_keywords = []
dept_keywords = []
topic_keywords = []

For attribute in [location, dept, topic]:
  1. list all titles that don't have a location yet
  2. manually extract a common location keyword (e.g. `grp`) and add it to keywords
  3. assign all titles that contain the new keyword the corresponding location
  4. back to one

  * do the same for each keywords
```

This works quite well if your keywords per attribute are only few.

For more advanced answers you should provide code and easy to copy data.